# geth console hangs after sendTransaction

Tags: go-ethereum

So, first of all, I want to clarify that I'm doing the transaction without the blockchain updated in my computer (I've read you can send transactions without it being updated).

This is my code:

`eth.sendTransaction({from: sender, to: receiver, value: ether_available - gas, gas:gas, nonce:2})`

Where `sender` is my address, `receiver` is the receiver, `value` is my total amount of ethereum minus the gas, and the `gas` is basically 50gwei * 21000 (all converted). My account only have 2 outer transactions so I set the `nonce` to 2, as I've read in a reddit post.

After executing the command, the console hangs and nothing happens (waited for 15 minues) until I do ctrl+C, then it says `Error: authentication needed: password or unlock`, but I first did `personal.unlockAccount(eth.coinbase)` and got `True` as response.

Someone knows if this is normal? Should I re-download all the blockchain and try again? (I know from the past that downloading the whole blockchain is a pain in the ass).

Comment: I don't know if it will help with the issue you're having, but gas should be 21000 and gasPrice should be 50gwei. value should probaby be ether_available - gas * gasPrice.

Comment: I think if you don't add gasPrice, it takes gas as the gas*gasPrice